# Synchronization of flow in UML Sequence Diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

How to synchronize flow after sending two asynchronous messages?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an explicit construct for this in sequence diagrams afaik.  You would have to annotate the diagram with a comment/constraint to indicate the need for synchronisation before further action.

Have you considered an [Activity Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram)?  They have specific notation for parallelism & synchronisation.